# sending multiple data in ajax post method in jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    var xmlHttp = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest(); //To support the browsers IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For the browsers IE6, IE5 
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error due to old verion of browser upgrade your browser");
    }
}

var xmlhttp = new getXmlHttpRequestObject(); //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

function servletPost()
{
    if(xmlhttp)    
    { 

        var comp_to = document.getElementById("comp_to").value;
        var comp_subject = document.getElementById("comp_subject").value;       
        var comp_letter = document.getElementById("comp_letter").value;        
        var date_time = document.getElementById("date_time").value;

        if(comp_to==""||comp_subject==""||comp_letter==""||date_time=="")    
        {     
            document.getElementById("redSignal").style.display='block';    
            document.getElementById("redSignal").innerHTML="All Fields are necessary";     
        }    
        else    
        {    
            xmlhttp.open("POST","complaintHandler",true);    
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServletPost;    
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            var data_string="to="+comp_to+"&subject="+comp_subject+"&complaint="+comp_letter+"&date_time="+date_time;    
            xmlhttp.send(data_string);     
        }    
    }
}

function handleServletPost() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("greenSignal").style.display='block';
            document.getElementById("greenSignal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("redSignal").style.display='block';
            document.getElementById("redSignal").innerHTML="Error Code ="+xmlhttp.status; 
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the problem of error code 404 
What could be the problem in this code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Error 404 itself says that your URL is wrong .

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","complaintHandler-wrong",true);
```

check this URL 1st .

Comment: complaintHandler is servlet what should be the posible way to use servlet here

Comment: there must be some URL to it right ? check your servlet mapping . like 

http://localhost:8080/projectName/complaintHandler

Comment: do i have to give the full path of servlet or something else

Comment: No not the path of servlet but the URL Mapped to servlet . You need to map your servlet in a XML file or using the annotation. if you have used a mapping like /xyz , the give the URL from the root like http://localhost:8080/xyz

Comment: my servlet is in default package with url pattern /complaintHandler

Comment: then url will be like 

http://host/contextRoot/complaintHandler

contextRoot is the root of your application you have defined at the time of project creation .

Answer (score 0):

[ERROR 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) Says. The requested Http request is not present or wrong.

Please check your **"complaintHandler"** It might be complaintHandler.jsp , kind of...

Please go through this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp) for your future use.

Comment: it is not a jsp file it is servlet